# Postgres how to find numeric element in json array (revision)

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

table name: muscle_groups
fields: id, name, segment_ids
data:

```
{"f": [], "m": [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39]}
```

tried many variations like:

```
select id, name, segment_ids->>"m"
where 5 = any(json_array_element(segment_ids->>"m")
```

Comment: Is that really an array of different objects?

Comment: The data looks like this.  {"f": [], "m": [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39]}. It was late at night, it's valid JSON

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the contains operator `@>`

```
select *
from muscle_groups 
where segment_ids @> '{"m": [5]}'
```